# FunctionalInterface implementation using variable count of params

Tags: java, java-8

In my library I have a simple adapter interface to register.

```
Adapter firstAdapter = new FirstAdapter(String someParam);
Adapter secondAdapter = new SecondAdapter(int otherParam, String eventAnotherParam);
something.register(firstAdapter)
    .register(secondAdapter);
```

Where adapter gets parameters in the constructor.

I'd like to be able to use an adapter of FunctionalInterface type but in this part I couldn't know, how many params or even of what types there could be needed to pass inside the lambda to evaluate.

Is there any way to solve this issue? I'd like to be able do something like this:

```
something.register(firstAdapter)
    .register(secondAdapter)
    .register((String whatever, String whateverElse) -> whatever.equalsTo(whateverElse))
    .register((int i) -> i>5);
```

EDIT {dsh}:

Interfaces could be something like this but it doesn't realy matter, it's just abstraction:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Adapter {
  boolean test();
}

interface Something {
  Something register(Adapter adapter);
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of your interface/abstract class `Adapter`?  Is it actually a functional interface? (the constructors of the implementation classes are irrelevant)  What is the class of `something`?  Specifically, what is the signature of (each of the) `register()` methods?

Comment: With the interface definitions you added to your question, you can not have the lambdas you have in your question: the lambda will be an instance of an anonymous subclass of `Adapter`, whose only method accpets 0 arguments.  You say the interfaces don't matter, except they are crucial to Java's lambda.

Comment: I know that. That's why I asked that question. A just wanted some proposals like kocko did in his answer. And that's why I've said that interface does not matter. I say it again, it's just an abstraction, the final result can look much more different.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes, the varags will be an array.

So you can implement the functional interface as:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface TestFunctionalInterface<T> {
    public Boolean test(T... args);
}
```

and then create lambdas like this:

```
something.register(firstAdapter)
         .register(secondAdapter)
         .register((Integer[] x) -> (x[0] > 5))
         //or
         .register(x -> ((int) x[0] > 5)
         //or
         .register(x -> x[0].equals(x[1]);
```

Note that here I'm not listing *each* of the lambda parameters, but rather refer to them as they are an array.

Of course, you can change the input/return types of the functional interface to something more specific, instead of using Generics, as shown in my example.

Comment: Right. That came to my mind, too. But honestly it's pretty ugly. :-)

Comment: The other possible solution is to have a bunch of overloaded `register` methods, each taking a different functional interface as a parameter. Even  this solution is not the best in terms of code-cleanness, you'd avoid producing duplicated-or-very-similar code.

Comment: Yes. The other solution that came to my mind is to have rigid Something interface to accept only particular type of object and pass it to adapters, e.g.: Something<T> and Adapter<T>. But that means to bind adapters to the parent and I don't like it, too.

Comment: And the third solution that comes to mind, is to *wrap* the objects within some container, since their count is unknown (e.g. `Set`, `List`), instead of dealing with varargs.

Comment: Interesting question, yes...can you make the `register` method generic, so that the type is specified every time the method is called. The container can be parameterized by this type. Actually, this doesn't make the solution easier